# Why does the phrase "a letter from employer" not require an article before "employer"?

Tags: grammar, articles, zero-article

Could somebody please explain why the phrase "a letter from employer" uses a zero article before the word "employer"? I understand that an indefinite article may be used here but what is the meaning behind the use of a zero article?

The phrase is taken from the "Visiting the UK" [website](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk#demonstrating-personal-circumstances):

> proof of earnings, such as **a letter from employer** confirming
> employment details (start date of employment, salary, role, company
> contact details)

Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.  It shouldn't have a zero article.  You shouldn't assume that all text you find online is a perfect example of English, even if it's from a government website. Humans can and do make mistakes.

Comment: It's not the kind of context where anyone cares about "strict grammar", and there's no scope for misunderstanding (they obviously won't accept a letter from ***your friend's*** employer). I wouldn't call it a "mistake", and I doubt whoever actually *wrote* it would think it should be revised. Where would it all end? You might as well insist it should continue with *...confirming **your** employment details.*

Comment: I note that an earlier bullet point does say _your employer_. Omitting it from this sentence was either accidental or because the meaning was clear without it.